# How to make prediction from the last datapoint of test set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, random-forest

I am conducting a time series prediction project. My task is to forecast sales amount in December when having data from January to November. I split data into train and test set. I already applied Randomforestregression to predict on test set. However, I don't know how to use the model to predict the December sales amount. Could you please let me know how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What library did you use? Python does not have `Randomforestregression` but you haven't added the actual library tag

Comment: I use sklearn.ensemble  to import RandomForestRegressor. Could you let me know how I can use the model that I built to predict sales amount in December? Thank you.

Comment: That wasn't what I was suggesting. I said you hadn't added the correct tags to get the attention of people who can help

Comment: There is not any tag for RandomForestRegressor

Comment: Sure, but there is one for `scikit-learn`, which I added. As I said in my initial comment - what "library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have finished already with cleaning the data you and already split them into `training` and `testing` dataset. You can simply put them through this `pipline` function I have created. This `generic function` which takes any algorithm and data as input and makes the model, performs cross-validation and generates prediction for `testing` dataset.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as ply
import cufflinks as cf

cf.go_offline()


#Define target and ID columns:
target = 'sales'
IDcol = ['months']
predictors = [x for x in training.columns if x not in [target]+IDcol]

alg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200,max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=100,n_jobs=4)
test = modelfitting(alg, training, testing, predictors, target)
coef5 = pd.Series(alg.feature_importances_, predictors).sort_values(ascending=False)
coef5.iplot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances')

for_plot = test
for_plot = for_plot[['sales prediction']]
for_plot.iplot()


def modelfitting(alg, training, testing, predictors, target):
    # Fit the algorithm on the data
    alg.fit(training[predictors], training[target])

    # Predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(training[predictors])

    # Perform cross-validation:
    cv_score = cross_val_score(alg, training[predictors], training[target], cv=20, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
    cv_score = np.sqrt(np.abs(cv_score))

    # Print model report:
    print "\nModel Report"
    print "RMSE : %.4g" % np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(training[target].values, dtrain_predictions))
    print "CV Score : Mean - %.4g | Std - %.4g | Min - %.4g | Max - %.4g" % (
    np.mean(cv_score), np.std(cv_score), np.min(cv_score), np.max(cv_score))

    # Predict on testing data:
    testing["sales prediction"] = alg.predict(testing[predictors])

    return testing
```

I’ve put in self-explanatory comments. Please feel free to discuss in comments if you face difficulties in understanding the code.

Comment: Hi, my question is when we have only data from Jan to Nov and we have to predict the data in Dec. How can we use the trained model to predict the future value in time series (not predict (X_test) and compare to Y_test)?

Comment: so, as long as you have trained the model, as the function shows above, you can simply pass your `test` dataset to make prediction. The model will make prediction using `testing["prediction"] = alg.predict(testing[predictors])`. Even if you pass it with more months, like Dec-Feb. It will make predictions according to the trained model to the testing dataset

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I have no training data for December. Let's say. My data frame is only 2 columns (month and sales ) from Jan to Nov. I don't know how to predict December from model.

Comment: well, your dataframe with only 2 columns from Jan to Nov is the training variable in my code; while the other dataframe with only one date "Dec" is the testing variable in my code. Once you train "fit" the training dataset, the model can predict the "sales" in the testing dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much